# changing value of an instance of a class from another class

Tags: python, pytorch

I have  training and test dataset as Pytorch Tensor objects and I want to change their values from another class, is this somehow possible? The code below does not change their values:

```
class BO:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = DataCollector().df_subset
        self.risk = DataCollector().risk_subset.unique(dim=0)
        self.device = torch.device('cpu')
        self.X_init = None
        self.outs_init = torch.zeros(0)
        self.y_init = []

        if torch.cuda.is_available():
           self.device = torch.device('cuda:7')

    def create_init_X_Y(self):
        '''
        Creates the initial X and y values.
        '''
        model.TrainDataset().df = self.data
        _, loss = model.train()
```

I need to overwrite the value of model.TrainDataset().df with the value of self.data.

Comment: What do you expect `model` to refer to in this context? Why? Where does it come from? More importantly, *how are you trying* to use this code, and *how are you verifying* that the change doesn't happen? Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We can't possibly explain the behaviour you observe, because the important part of the process is somewhere else.

Comment: Also: what do you expect `model.TrainDataset()` to do? Are you expecting it to give back an *already existing* object? Because if it gives you a *new* object, then obviously, setting the `.df` of that object is rather unlikely to have an effect on any other objects. *What does the documentation say* about `model.TrainDataset`?